# Email Validation Error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i'm new to javascript & not able to understand the Email validation using JS. I gave a try but ended up with few Errors. My code is given below, please help me out!
Hoping for a positive result!

```
function validEmail()
{
var email= document.forms["validation"]["enteremail"].value;
var reg = (/^[0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/);
if (reg.test(email) == false )
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  } 
    }
```

Comment: That's nice. Are you going to say what the "few Errors" are?

Comment: Well, It shows "Not a valid email address" even after entering a valid one :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
function validEmail()
{
var mail = document.getElementById('mail').value; // where `mail` is id of your input form
var email = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;

  if (mail.match(email))
  {
      alert("Your Email : " + mail);
  }
  else
  {
      alert("Invalid Email !!!");
  }
}
```

Html:

```
<input type="text=" id="mail"><input type="button" id="k" value="check" onclick="validEmail()">
```

`Note`: When you support invalid email it will alert `Invalid Email !!!` otherwise `Your Email : example@gmail.com`

Comment: Did that code work properly for you buddy? It got few errors too :/

Comment: @user2035893 Yes it is working snippet. What is the problem ? I'll update answer and see it

Answer (score 1):

Try this one it is working fine for me...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function ShowAlert() {
  var email = document.getElementById('txtEmailId');
  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
        alert('Please provide a valid email address');
        email.focus;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("Thanks for your intrest in us, Now you 
        will be able to receive monthly updates from us.");
        document.getElementById('txtEmailId').value = "";
    }
 }
 </script>
```